# eth.sign() method giving error

Tags: signature, console

I am using `eth.sign` from Ethereum wallet developer terminal and getting following error `rejection Error: Returned Error: The method eth_sign does not exist/is not available`

Please advise whats the problem. have tried everything (etc. swapping the arguments etc.)

Comment: Hi there. What options did you pass to your Geth instance when you started it?

Comment: I did not use geth terminal, I m using console from Ethereum walllet developer tools

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by using `web3.eth.accounts.sign` instead only pain I had to face to extract private key out of mist wallet

Answer (score 0):

Method `web3.eth.sign` signs message on remove, i.e. node, side using private key stored by the node.  This method does not work with Infura, because Infura nodes do not store any private keys.

You probably need to sign message locally on client side using `web3.eth.accounts.sign`, but in this case you will need to provide private key to be used for signing.